# nested url but not nested state or view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states that share the same view and have nested urls.

```
{
  name: 'widget',
  url: '/widget/:widget',
  template: '<widget></widget>'
},
{
  name: 'widget.version',
  url: '/version/:version',
  template: '<widget></widget>'
}
```

The first one renders fine but the second one doesn't at all, the `<widget>` component is never mounted. None of the resolves I've added to the `widget.version` route are never fired either.

Also, the `<widget>` template never uses `ui-view` (it doesn't have to).

I also tried this to avoid nested states altogether, but the same thing happens

```
{
  name: 'widget',
  url: '^/widget/:widget',
  template: '<widget></widget>'
},
{
  name: 'widgetversion',
  url: '^/widget/:widget/version/:version',
  template: '<widget></widget>'
}
```

How can I get my `/version/:version` nested url to render?

Comment: So when you go to `/version/1` , it does not render  `<widget>` ?

Comment: @Santosh nope, nothing inside my top level ui-view renders

Comment: can you post the sample code?

Comment: im just going with `/widget/:widget?version`, makes everything a lot easier.